# Prism 7.x: Scoped regions with the navigation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

I am upgrading the sample project of **Children-RegionManagerAware-Complete** (Brian Lagunas explained in pluralsight using Prism 5) to Prism 7.2 and .NET 8. It appears I need to handle all the initialization work in `App` previously was in `Bootstrapper`. However, I can’t figure out:

1. Where to handle:

   `ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver((viewType) =>
   {
   var viewName = viewType.FullName;
   var viewAssemblyName = viewType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
   var viewModelName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}ViewModel, {1}", viewName, viewAssemblyName);
   return Type.GetType(viewModelName);
   });`
2. Where to handle:

   `var regionManager = RegionManager.GetRegionManager(Shell);
   RegionManagerAware.SetRegionManagerAware(Shell, regionManager);`

TIA.

Comment: I am facing what I think is a similar problem.    I cannot find the example you talk about in your question, however.  None of the Prism courses on PluralSight seem to match it.   Do you have a link to the course or the sample project anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

> Where to handle: `ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver`

`PrismApplicationBase.ConfigureViewModelLocator`

> Where to handle: `RegionManagerAware.SetRegionManagerAware`

`PrismApplicationBase.InitializeShell` (use the parameter instead of the property)

Comment: Thank you, Haukinger! Where is InitializeShell? There is no Bootstrapper with Prism 7.x. TIA!

Comment: @Frank not 100% sure whether you're trolling? If you take a look at the code (https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/PrismApplicationBase.cs or just decompile in visual studio) you'll find all the methods that are there to override.